# Face exists but no edge

Tags: faces, edges

I've been learning Blender for a while now, and there's this problem I couldn't figure out the answer, even after searching for it.

There's this edge I want to move, on the same z axis :

[image: Edge I want to move]

And when I want to move this edge like this :

[image: No edge but a face]

There's still this face existing even if I moved the vertices and the edge. How could I remove this overflow ? Why does it even exist ? I'm using Blender 2.79. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It acts like this because it tries to create a face between your 4 vertices. To do what you want to do you will have to create a transverse edge like that:

[image]

Comment: Oh, I see, edges are this importants in order to sculpt objects. I see ! Thanks a lot !